# How do I lock specific columns in an existing excel sheet?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to lock specific columns in an existing excel sheet. I am using the code below but I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'protection'

Can anyone please guide me where I am going wrong and how can I get this done?

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Protection

path = r"C:\Users\sarashiv\ABC.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
ws.protection.sheet = True
ws.protection.enable()
ws['A:D'].protection.disable()

wb.save(path)
```

Comment: It is always best to post the full Traceback. In this case: which line is causing the error?

Comment: ws['A:D'].protection.disable() - this line is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to crack this after reading multiple posts. I could not find a way to unlock columns, but found a way to unlock cells. I used a for loop to unlock columns by unlocking many cells.

```
    wb = load_workbook(path_1)
    ws = wb.active
    ws.protection.sheet = True
    ws.protection.enable()

    for x in range(1, 100): #Unlocks first 100 rows in first 2 columns
        for y in range(1,3):
            ws.cell(row = x, column = y).protection = Protection(locked=False, hidden=False)
            wb.save(path_1)
```